# How to delete rows in R, which contains the same "set" of data within a column

Tags: r, string, vector, duplicates, set

I have a dataframe of data with two columns `lift` and `skill.set`. Within `skill.set`, contains a string of skills separated by commas. For example, there might be an obversation with the string "Excel, PowerPoint" and another with "PowerPoint, Excel." These two observations are capturing the same data, and I only want to keep one of them (the one with the highest lift). I can't think of an efficient way of doing this without naively turning each string into a vector with elements separated by comma, and then writing a for-loop that compares each `skill.set` data to each other `skill.set` data.

Example dataframe:

```
df = structure(list(lift = c(5.71421247789905, 4.65329289252856, 5.87820023244231, 
21.1815668998877), skill.set = c("JavaScript,Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.,Microsoft.Word,Python,Microsoft.PowerPoint", 
"Microsoft.PowerPoint,Microsoft.Word,Python,SQL,Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.", 
"Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.,Microsoft.Word,Python,SQL,Microsoft.PowerPoint", 
"Analytics...Text.Mining,Natural.Language.Processing,Python")), .Names = c("lift", 
"skill.set"), row.names = 239:242, class = "data.frame")
```

Desired dataframe:

```
structure(list(lift = c(5.71421247789905, 5.87820023244231, 21.1815668998877
), skill.set = c("JavaScript,Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.,Microsoft.Word,Python,Microsoft.PowerPoint", 
"Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.,Microsoft.Word,Python,SQL,Microsoft.PowerPoint", 
"Analytics...Text.Mining,Natural.Language.Processing,Python")), .Names = c("lift", 
"skill.set"), row.names = c(239L, 241L, 242L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following:

```
df[!duplicated(sapply(strsplit(df$skill.set, ","), function(x) 
    paste0(sort(x), collapse = ","))), ]
#         lift
#239  5.714212
#240  4.653293
#242 21.181567
#                                                                           skill.set
#239 JavaScript,Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.,Microsoft.Word,Python,Microsoft.PowerPoint
#240        Microsoft.PowerPoint,Microsoft.Word,Python,SQL,Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.
#242                       Analytics...Text.Mining,Natural.Language.Processing,Python
```

Explanation: Split entries in `df$skill.set` on `","`, then sort entries and concatenate; keep only non-duplicated entries.

---

### Update

To only retain the row with the largest `lift` value we can use `aggregate`:

```
setNames(aggregate(
    lift ~ sapply(strsplit(skill.set, ","), function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ",")),
    df,
    max), rev(names(df)))
#1                       Analytics...Text.Mining,Natural.Language.Processing,Python
#2 JavaScript,Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.,Microsoft.PowerPoint,Microsoft.Word,Python
#3        Microsoft.Excel..MS.Excel.,Microsoft.PowerPoint,Microsoft.Word,Python,SQL
#       lift
#1 21.181567
#2  5.714212
#3  5.878200
```

Comment: I see the logic now, very good explanation. This method will always keep the first unique set and delete the duplicated one. But what if the lift value is higher for the second set (which is the one that I want to keep)?

Comment: @KevinSun For what it's still worth, I've added a base R solution using `aggregate`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(skill.set, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(lift) %>%
  arrange(skill.set) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(id, skill.set) %>%
  unite(skill.set, 2:6, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(skill.set) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(lift), max)
```

You decide which `lift` you want to keep by changing `max` to whatever you prefer. Also, change `2:6` based on the column numbers that were produced by the preceding `spread`.

Comment: Very appropriate use of `separate_rows`.